# Expression tree : avoid DynamicInvoke

Tags: c#, delegates, expression-trees

I use expression trees to build delegates at runtime :

```
Type type = GetType();
ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(type);
...
Delegate delegate = Expression.Lambda(*something*, parameterType).Compile();
```

I don't know at compile time the type returned by the method GetType(). Is it possible to invoke my delegate without using the expensive DynamicInvoke() method ?

**Edit :**

In my application I have a base abstract class :

```
public abstract class Frame
{
    public string RawContent { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

At runtime the application will use some objects which inherits Frame; the type of these objects is not known at compile time, because they will be loaded with MEF (plug-ins). The goal of the application is to filter the objects with erroneous data : for example, if the program must process some objects of a class like this one :

```
public class Frame01 : Frame
{
    public int Counter6hours { get; set; }

    public int DeltaCounter6hours { get; set; }
}
```

I would like my users to be able to write, in the configuration file of the application, something like this :

```
<filtersSection>
    <filters>
            <filter class="Frame01" expression="Counter6hours < 0" />
            <filter class="Frame01" expression="DeltaCounter6hours > 2500" />
    </filters>
<filtersSection>
```

I manage to create an expression tree and compile it into a delegate for each filter. But I can't cast it into Func because I don't know the type Frame01 at compile time... So, for the moment, I use the method DynamicInvoke() of my delegates, which invokes in a late-bound way the underlying methods. The application will have to handle a large amount of objects, and I fear performance issues... So, in this example, I'm trying to build programmatically a Func object, but I'm not sure it's possible.

PS : Excuse me for my poor English...

Comment: Can you not just make the return type `object`?

Comment: @leppie : the resulting delegate is a method which takes an object (unknown at compile time) and returns a bool. Do you mean I should try to cast my delegate as a Func<???, object> ?

Comment: @schglurps - It sounds like you want to cast it to `Func<object, bool>`.

Comment: @leppie : I just tried to cast my delegate to Func<object, bool>, and I got a runtime error. Do you know a way to build programmatically such an object ?

Comment: I really don't understand what do you want. I don't see anything that could be in any way related to `Func<object, bool>` in your code, could you fix that? How come you have object of the correct type, but you need to treat it as `object`? Can't you use generics? Could you explain *why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: @svick : Excuse me if I was not clear enough. In fact my application must process a sequence of objects; I do not know at compile time their type. Two objects in this sequence can have different types. I would like to filter these objects, basing upon some rules, and I try to build these rules with expression trees.

Comment: What kind of rules? How are they related to the types of objects in the collection? I think an example of those rules would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still not completely clear to me this is what you want, but I think all you need is a cast: your expression will have a parameter of type `Frame`, cast it to `Frame01` and then run your filters on that.

In code:

```
var type = typeof(Frame01);

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Frame));
var casted = Expression.Convert(param, type);

// this part will be dynamic in your actual code
var condition = Expression.LessThan(
    Expression.Property(casted, "Counter6hours"), Expression.Constant(0));

var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<Frame, bool>>(condition, param)
    .Compile();
```

With that, the following tests pass:

```
Assert.IsTrue(result(new Frame01 { Counter6hours = -1 }));
Assert.IsFalse(result(new Frame01 { Counter6hours = 1 }));
Assert.Throws<InvalidCastException>(() => result(new Frame02()));
```

Comment: OK, finally I understand what you mean ! In fact I didn't notice until your message that the function Expression.Convert() exists. With this I can finally avoid to use the DynamicInvoke() method. Thank you for your help ! And your patience !

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you want to end up with a `Func<object, bool>`

So, you have to build your expression tree taking a parameter of type `object`

Something like this will work:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var c = Expression.Constant(true);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(c,p);
var fn = ( Func<object, bool> ) lambda.Compile();
```

Then:

```
bool b = fn( ...some object... );
```